# Currency disappears when exported as PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, format, report, currency

When I export my report to pdf, the currency disappears.

[image]

Here is the code:

````
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!dTransactionAmount.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                                    <FontSize>9pt</FontSize>
                                    <Format>=Code.getChargeCurrency()</Format>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns> 

Public Shared Function getChargeCurrency() As string
    if NOT chargeNum = invoiceNumber then
        currency ="'$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00)"
    else 
        currency="#,0.00;(#,0.00)"
        
    end if
    
    chargeNum = invoiceNumber
    Return currency
    End Function ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No really an answer but mu guess....

If you render directly to PDF via a url does it work then? Test it using a url something like

```
http://myReportServer/ReportServer?/myReportName&rs:Format=PDF
```

If this works then I suspect the variable is getting set when you render to screen so when you render to PDF chargenum is already = invoicenumber.

I don't know enough about your situation to know what the best solution is but you could try to store the `Globals.RenderFormat` value ina variable and check that this has not changed when you check to see if the other two variable have changed.

Something like...

```
if chargeNum <> invoiceNumber AND lastRenderFormat <> currentRenderFormat then
    currency ="'$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00)"
else 
    currency="#,0.00;(#,0.00)"
    
end if

chargeNum = invoiceNumber
lastRenderFormat = currentRenderFormat
```

Comment: Hi, Im very new to SSRS reporting. Does this mean, when I export to PDF, it reloads/ run the report again ? If that makes sense? I though it just translates to PDF.

Comment: That right. It uses the cached data but it renders it all again. Think of it as "Render to HTML" when you view it on screen. If you want another format, it has to use a different renderer and start again.

If you are very new, can I assume you inherited this report from another developer?

Comment: Yes and No, I am redeveloping it, but this part of the code is already mine.

Comment: I'm off to bed now it's 1am here but I would be interested to know what sets the chargenum variable initially. It seems like you might be able to do this with a simple expression in the format property but I'm not sure what data you have in your dataset or what how variables get set etc.

Comment: thank you ! i just set chargenum as 0 from the start. It acts like a counter

Comment: So, ignoring anything you have done before what is the logic behind deciding whether or not the textbox should be formatted as currency or not? If you can determine this based solely on the data in your dataset, edit the question to show an example of the dataset output.

Comment: the dataset won't determine the formatting. The dataset would show the invoices per client, and in the report, the first line should show the currency and the rest wouldn't

Comment: OK, edit you question and show report report design including groups. Also show a sample of your data. I'm 99% certain you will be able to do what you want with a very simple expression, no VB code required. If I guess now we'll be going round in circles so just post this stuff and I'll help.

Comment: Solved it ! For some reason, something is going wrong with the chargeNumber=invoiceNumber when I place it in the format line. I removed that one, and placed it in another place and it works. Would you know where else to get tutorials on SSRS online? I would def need it. I need to learn more about maximizing the use of the expressions. Appreciate all your help !

Comment: TBH The MS Docs are pretty good. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15 Writing expressions is no harder than writing Excel formulae.

Comment: As an example if you have, in your report, a rowgroup that was grouping by invoice and the rowgroup was called `grpInvoice` then you could simply place this in the format property `=IIF(RowNumber("grpInvoice") = 1, "c2", "n2")` . That's it -done. c2 is "currency format to 2 decimals; n2 is numeric to 2 decimals and including thousand separators.

Comment: thank you very much with all your help!! I tried the rownumber code before, but the dataset was designed to generate all invoice for different clients. So rownumber would only be successful for the first client. Next invoices would start where the row of previous invoice would end.

Comment: Not if you had a row group that grouped by invoice which would be the standard way of doing this type of task.

Comment: Interesting. It does have a grouping by the client. I can try that one :)